# JDA How to send signals from my server to the client?

Tags: websocket, discord, discord-jda

As mentioned in the question, I would like to trigger the sending of a message to the discord channel when a specific event occurs on my server, but the message content needs to have a user ID, which can only be obtained from the client.

My idea is to send a signal to the client through my server, and after receiving the signal, the client will send a message. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What signal? What client? What event? You need to be a lot more specific with your wording. We can't help you if we can't understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.